# Getting throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);

Tags: node.js, angular, logging

I am trying to add r7insight_node to my angular and node app but I am getting this error while creating new object of Logger

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type
>   string. Received type undefined at validateString
>   (internal/validators.js:125:11)

this is all I am adding in my server.ts

```
const Logger = require('r7insight_node');

const logger = new Logger({ token: '<token>' , region: '<region>'});

logger.warning("I'll put this over here, with the rest of the fire.");
```

Please help me with this one

Comment: Just to be clear, in your own code, you've set the token to be your actual token and the region to be one of 'eu' or 'us' etc.? Could you also include the full stack trace?

Comment: you've mentioned this is a `.ts` file. Try to use import instead of require. So it will be: ```import Logger from 'r7insight_node';```

Comment: Yes I have actual token and region in my code and @gmadr I have tried it as well. no luc. Same error

Answer (score 2):

For other people having this issue, I had it (in a typescript project) because my tsconfig was set to target ES2021 but babel was not transforming some of the 2021 properties. Not sure why it led to this exact issue; guessing that a different error along the way produced it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I was using mongoose and I noticed I did not require mongoose and that's why it is throwing this error.